# Phone number validation using javascript satisfying conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I need the phone number validations satisfying the following conditions.I am having separate code .But i found quite difficult while 
combining the regular expression.

1.The entire phone number can be 64 characters long.

2.1st character of the phone number can be + or 0.

3.2nd, 3rd, 4th character of the phone number can be  ( or ) or - or space or numbers 0 to 9.

4. 5th to 64th character of the phone number can be  ( or ) or - or space or * or # or numbers 0 to 9 or alphabets both small and capital

Kindly guide.Thanks in advance.

```js
var num1 = /^[\+0]$/; // first character 0 or +

var num2 = /^\d(?: ?\d+)*$/; // space 

var num3 = /^\d{0,64}$/; // 64 character long
```

Comment: digits or characters? why you want alphabets in phone number? ( your condition 4)

Comment: Cannot add like:
+ <input> - <input> - <input> for phone? then type=number will do...for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really just break up the problem a bit.

1. make sure the input is less than or equal to 64 characters
2. Just check the first regex part and second regex part
3. Check the rest of the string

```js
function test_example () {
  let input = document.getElementById("example").value
  if (input.length <= 64)
  {
    if (input[0] !== "+" && input[0] !== "0")
    {
      console.log("first false")    
      return false
    }
    
    let second = input.substring(1, 5)
    if (!second.match(/^[0-9() ]+$/))
    {
      console.log("second false")
      return false
    }
    
    let third = input.substring(5)
    console.log(third)
    if (!third.match(/^[A-z0-9()*# -]+$/))
    {
      console.log("third false")
      return false
    }
    
    console.log("okay")
    return true
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example" />
<button onclick="test_example()">test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Lau.It was very much useful to me.